# How can I use agenda view to find all task containing subtasks?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The possibility within Org mode to organize tasks hierarchically makes it suited for managing projects. Hence the the overal project goal ("build a new house") can be the parent task with many subtasks (children task). During my weekly review I would like to make an agenda view that only shows me tasks that has subtasks. Is that possible? Or even more general, can I make an agenda view that only shows tasks of a certain hierarchical depth?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that I know of:

1. Create a `PROJECT` to-do keyword, and set the top-level project headlines to this keyword.  Then you can make a custom agenda view that shows all `PROJECT` items.
2. You'll need to write a custom agenda function that skips headlines you don't want to see.  I can't write this for you, but here are some really good resources:

   - [org-helpers.el](https://github.com/leoc/org-helpers.el/blob/master/org-helpers.el)
   - [org-custom-agenda-views.el](https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/org-custom-agenda-views.el)
   - ["Org-mode, GTD, and the Pomodoro technique"](http://headhole.org/organisation/2012/08/22/org-mode-gtd-and-the-pomodoro-technique/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! it might be helpful to mine: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/org-mode-list-done-tasks-with-parent-level-two-task-as-context

Answer (score 0):

The `LEVEL` [special property](http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html) tells you the depth of an entry.

> In addition to the Special properties, one other “property” can also be used. LEVEL represents the level of an entry.

For example a search `LEVEL>1` will match any entry with more than one leading star.  I don't see any straightforward way to match entries having children.

Comment: Thanks! But is the `LEVEL` property something I have to generate myself inside a `PROPERTY` drawer, or is it something org mode define automatically? I cannot find anything about level when search in `org mode property level` on the web, or searching `LEVEL` among variables or function (C-h v or C-h f) inside Emacs.

Comment: `LEVEL` isn't a normal property, but you can still search for it and it works just like a property.