# Emacs org-mode custom agenda view for each project

Tags: org-mode

I have a project.org file that as a * Project subtree where each project I'm currently working on is tracked. I'd like to create a custom agenda view that separates out each project by project so I can see what items I have open for each project. I've been able to do something similar for work that has been delegated by using tags, but in this case I don't want to have to tag every item in order to separate it out. How might I go about breaking my agenda view up based on the subtrees in my project file? Example below

```
* Project
** Project 1
*** TODO Task 1
** Project 2
*** TODO Task 2
* Hiring
** Position 1
*** DONE Job Requirements
** Position 2
*** TODO Job Requirements
```

Should result in something like the following:

> Project 1 unfinished tasks:
>
> ```
> agenda:     TODO [#A] Task 1
> ```
>
> =======================================================================================================================
>
> Project 2 unfinished tasks:
>
> ```
> agenda:      TODO [#A] Task 1
> ```
>
> =======================================================================================================================
> Position 2 unfinished tasks:
>
> ```
> inbox:      TODO Job Requirements
> ```

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14870/how-can-i-use-agenda-view-to-find-all-task-containing-subtasks).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable. This is a setup to create an agenda for two project files:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("p" "Projects"
 ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-files '("project1.org"))))
  (agenda "" ((org-agenda-files '("project2.org"))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible out of the box. I'd suggest using category, project name, and `TODO` entry all on the same line. You will also have to label your level one headings (agenda and inbox respectively) using the `CATEGORY` property by pressing `C-c C-x p`. For example:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("u" "Unfinished tasks"
         ((tags "LEVEL=3+CATEGORY={agenda\\|inbox}"
                ((org-agenda-prefix-format 
                  " %-12c %-12(car (last (org-get-outline-path)))")
                 (org-agenda-overriding-header "Unfinished tasks")))))))
```

produces:

```
Unfinished tasks
 agenda       Project 1   TODO Task 1
 agenda       Project 2   TODO Task 2
 inbox        Position 1  DONE Job Requirements
 inbox        Position 2  TODO Job Requirements
```

Another options is to indent subtasks under project headings:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("u" "Unfinished tasks"
         ((tags "LEVEL>1+CATEGORY=\"agenda\"")
          (tags "LEVEL>1+CATEGORY=\"inbox\""))
         ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %-12c %l%l")
          (org-agenda-overriding-header "Unfinished tasks")))))
```

```
Unfinished tasks
 agenda           Project 1
 agenda             TODO Task 1
 agenda           Project 2
 agenda             TODO Task 2
Unfinished tasks
 inbox            Position 1
 inbox              DONE Job Requirements
 inbox            Position 2
 inbox              TODO Job Requirements
```